# Is NoSuchElementException a good alternative for ResourceNotFoundException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-data

Before Spring-Boot and Spring-Data 2.0, I used `org.springframework.boot.context.config.ResourceNotFoundException` to check if a instance of entity was in the database. I used the following exception handler in a controller:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public HttpStatus handleNotFoundResource() {
    return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Now, because repository methods return an optional, I used `java.util.NoSuchElementException` to do the job in the controller:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
public HttpStatus handleNotFoundResource() {
    return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Is it the best practice?

Comment: Could probably use `optional.orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);`

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` is much broader than your custom exception `ResourceNotFoundException` that you define to be thrown in a specific case : no entity/resource in the database.
Between the controller and the repository layer you can have other method invocations that throw `NoSuchElementException` (Collection methods, other Optional and still many others)  other than `Repository.findXXX().get()`.

So your idea *may* create undesirable side effects.
To prevent any regression, you should handle explicitly the `Optional` unwrapping such as `return Optional.orElseThrown(ResourceNotFoundException::new)`.
If you want to generalize it you could introduce a base class for your repository that does this processing.

Comment: I didn't realize that other methods can throw `NoSuchElementException`, but is it not desirable anyway? I thought one of the reasons why we love exception is *throw anywhere, catch once*.

Comment: In principal true, but would a 404 be the correct response for all occurrences of a NoSuchElementException? Maybe a 400 would be better, if it happens when processing the request body for example.

Comment: I didn't know this proverb. It is right. But the question is what do you catch here ? The "catch once" will be a "catch all and nothing" and the single way to exploit it correctly is logging something like "Houston we have a problem".  But even if other classes didn't throw this exception, you can use other `Optional` objects in  your service or controller that throw the exception for another reason than "no resource is found".

Comment: @banan3'14 But I know "write once, run anywhere" :)

Comment: @david I made it up, based on "write once, run anywhere" :D